# In Firestore cloud functions the forEach loop is returning a multiple of the number of items in database

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => ... cycles through snapshot once, twice, ...

Suppose I have 8 documents in a Cloud Firestore database then I'd expect 8 items would be returned when I run the code below.

```js
exports.GetNearestTransmitters = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
      db.collection('Transmitters').orderBy('siteID').get().then((snapshot) => {
          snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            getDistanceBetweenHomeAndTransmitter(doc);
          });
        }
      });
```

Problem: Sometimes 8 are returned, sometimes 16, sometimes 24

Why are the contents of the snapshot being cycled-through more than once?

Answer (score 0):

The Firestore Cloud Function retained state frequently, which isn't supposed to happen, because I didn't 'zero' the 'global variables' used in the GetNearestTransmitters() cloud function.

```js
var count;
var distanceArray;
var jsonArr;
var limit = 10;
var debugStr;
exports.GetNearestTransmitters = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
      // Zero the Global Variables
      count = 0;
      distanceArray = [
        []
      ];
      jsonArr = [];
      limit = 10;
      debugStr = "";
      let feCount = 0;

      db.collection('Transmitters').orderBy('siteID').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            console.log("No of 'Transmitters' in Firestore = " + querySnapshot.size);
            console.log("No of docs in snapshot = " + querySnapshot.docs.length);

            querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
              getDistanceBetweenHomeAndTransmitter(doc);
            });
```